# The pen tool in PS is applying curves when I did not tell it to. Hard to explain, check out attached images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool

So I am using the pen tool to trace a selection, but it is being weird.

[image]

So I put the line down and made a bit of a curve by holding down and moving the mouse.

[image: ![image 2] (http://imgur.com/gDFNLjA)]

Then I move my pen tool around, with rubber band on, and the curve is applied to the new segment! Why? How do I fix it? Even if I apply a new curve to the new segment the old one still persists in some part and mucks it up.

Thanks for the Help.

Comment: Sorry my images are broken :(. Here is the album on imgur.com http://imgur.com/a/s66eQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to press <kbd>Alt / Option</kbd> and <kbd>click</kbd> on the newly created anchor point do get rid of the predictive curve. If you don't do that, PS will create a predictive next curve based on your last one.

In the image below there's the normal curve created with the pen tool and the second image is with the same curve but after using <kbd>Alt / Option</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on the newly created anchor point to negate the auto curve.

[image]

Comment: For Mac users the: - Option key is the equivalent of Alt - Command key = Control key - Control = Mouse right click These are Bezier curves, used often in Illustrator for vector art.